# Łukasiewicz predicate logic?

Tags: java, java-8, predicate

Is there a way to emulate Łukasiewicz' three-valued logic with the Java API?

More concretely, I want to emulate Łukasiewicz' ['M' ("it is not false that...")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic#.C5.81ukasiewicz_logic) operator.

For example I need to construct this `Predicate<String>` which gives the following results:

```
predicate.test("0") = false
predicate.test(null) = true
predicate.test("1") = true
```

which when negated, gives:

```
predicate.negate().test("0") = true
predicate.negate().test(null) = true
predicate.negate().test("1") = false
```

If the value to test is `A`, my predicate calculates `MA`. What `negate()` does is calculate `¬MA` whereas I want it to calculate `M¬A`.

P.S. Don't bother working out an answer with a three-valued replacement for `Predicate` with a three-valued replacement of `boolean`, because I know well enough how to do that myself. I'm asking this question to find out if it's possible with pure Java8 with minimal extra coding effort.

Comment: For your example, what would the predicate return for a value that is not 0, 1 or null?

Comment: Depends on the predicate. I could have `a -> a==null || "0".equals(a)` and I could have `a -> a==null || !"1".equals(a)`. It always has `a==null` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is what you want:

```
static <T> Predicate<T> p(Predicate<? super T> o){ //(I'm not sure what to name this)
    return new Predicate<T>(){
        @Override
        public boolean test(T t) {
            return t == null || o.test(t);
        }
        @Override
        public Predicate<T> negate(){
            return p(o.negate());
        }
    };
}
....
Predicate<String> predicate = p(t -> !"0".equals(t));
```

If the value to test is null we return true, otherwise we use the original predicate. To negate we just negate the original predicate.

---

If null is not always the third value you could pass in another predicate to test for that:

```
static <T> Predicate<T> p(Predicate<? super T> isUnknown, Predicate<? super T> isTrue){
    return new Predicate<T>(){
        @Override
        public boolean test(T t) {
            return isUnknown.test(t) || isTrue.test(t);
        }
        @Override
        public Predicate<T> negate(){
            return p(isUnknown, isTrue.negate());
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Smallest to my problem. :)

Comment: Smallest solution*.   And I'll call it `PossiblyUnknownPredicate' or something

Answer (score 1):

It won't be possible to do that if we keep the default implementation of [`negate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#negate--) in the `Predicate` class: by default, this constructs a predicate that always return the opposite boolean value of the initial predicate. As such, it isn't possible to have both `predicate.test(null)` and `predicate.negate().test(null)` return `true`.

Therefore, we need to implement our own predicate. In the following implementation, a state is maintained with the `negate` boolean. It indicates the correct value to return for `trueValue` or `falseValue`. For the `thirdValue`, `true` is always returned. If the predicate is tested with a value that is neither one of the 3 values, `false` is always returned (this case wasn't mentioned in your question, so feel free to adapt this).

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Predicate<String> predicate = lukasiewicz("1", "0", null);

    System.out.println(predicate.test("0"));
    System.out.println(predicate.test(null));
    System.out.println(predicate.test("1"));

    System.out.println(predicate.negate().test("0"));
    System.out.println(predicate.negate().test(null));
    System.out.println(predicate.negate().test("1"));
}

private static <T> Predicate<T> lukasiewicz(T trueValue, T falseValue, T thirdValue) {
    class LukasiewiczPredicate implements Predicate<T> {

        private boolean negate; 

        private LukasiewiczPredicate(boolean negate) {
            this.negate = negate;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean test(T t) {
            if (Objects.equals(trueValue, t)) return negate;
            if (Objects.equals(falseValue, t)) return !negate;
            if (Objects.equals(thirdValue, t)) return true;
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Predicate<T> negate() {
            return new LukasiewiczPredicate(!negate);
        }

    };
    return new LukasiewiczPredicate(true);
}
```

Comment: I'm still tring to wrap my head around this (didn't to any formal logic recently), but: Does this also work as expected for more complex expressions? E.g. do things like `M(A -> M(!B))` (where `A` and `B` may be Lukasiewicz predicates) properly propagate the value and treatment of the "unknown" value through the expression tree? I thought that it *might* be necessary to create an own predicate class where not only `negate`, but also `and` and `or` are overridden accordingly - in the worst case, with some nasty `instanceof LukasiewiczPredicate` tests or even searches in the "expression tree"...

Comment: @Marco13 I don't think it's necessary to override `and` and `or` since they don't depend on `negate` (which to me is the crux of the problem). I've done a couple of tests and it seems all right.

Comment: I haven't thought of using a field to remember the 'negated-ness'. +1